# I have multiple activities and I want to add Drawer for all activities without use of FRAGMENTS in android

Tags: android, android-activity

I am new in Android,
using Android Studio.

in my project I had made multiple activities.
now I want to make one navigation drawer for all the activities.

I am not want to use Fragments.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't wanted to use fragments then the best method is to create a `BaseActivity` which extends `Activity` (or `AppCompactActivity`). Inside `onCreate` method do all the codings for navigation drawer.

Now for Which ever activity, navigation drawer is required you can extend the `BaseActivity`.

eg:

```
   public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity{
     ......
    }
```

Don't forget to include navigation drawer xml codes inside the layout files of different activities.

also you can use [include](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html) for reusing drawer layout.